# Why is my navigation bar jumbled up when the screen is tight? Also why do my headers interfere with it?

Tags: html, css

Here is the jsfiddle for it  http://jsfiddle.net/8PcxE/

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
                <div id="nav-container">
                    <ul id ="nav-list">
                        <li id=nav-title>lymbo</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Playmaps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../map.html">Map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
```

It is fine on a wider page, but when I run it on a small page everything is cramped and the options get pushed together making a zipper-like pattern.

My other problem is when I type something in my headers or paragraphs it will be at the top and intersecting with my navigation bar making it look like a mess.

My goal is to make a sort of "gradient" looking navigation bar hence the shadows.  But that also doesn't seem to look right.  If someone can give me some input on that, it would be much appreciated.

**I found that after I changed my nav-container CSS to position: relative from position: fixed it works out.  Are there any negative effects of doing this?**

Comment: Your navigation wraps to multiple lines when the window is too small to display it on one line. You'll need to decide what you want the navigation to do when the page shrinks. Do you want the navigation to wrap to multiple lines? Do you want a horizontal scrollbar to show? Do you want elements to change responsively to the window size?

Comment: Adding `"overflow: hidden;"` to `"# nav-container"` you prevent this break but hidden links.

Comment: btw: [`float: top` isn't a valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Comment: you could also set a min-width, to prevent this.

Comment: I want the horizontal scrollbar to show.  I tried setting a page width on my container but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've changed all the `<li>` to `inline`, the simplest solution would be to prevent wrapping on the `<ul>`:

```
#nav-list {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* ... */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Lt72p/

Comment: This is the simplest one and it does work, but when I make the browser width smaller it covers up the options on the nav bar.